# Select menu is not appearing properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap, i was using the select menu with the class .form-group but in some browsers the select is appearing different, so Im creating a custom select menu. But its not working properly, for example in large devices there is a lot of space but the text of the select menu is hidden because the select menu is small, like it appears in the image:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Do you know how to fix the issue?

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gLgv8n3q/

css:

```
<div class="container test  py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <h1 class="w-100 mr-auto my-0 h5 text-heading-blue font-weight-bold">Search </h1>
      <form class="mr-2">
        <select class="form__select font-size-xsm font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
          <option selected class="selected">Order By P0</option>
          <option>i1</option>
          <option>i2</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <form class="mr-2">
        <select class="form__select font-size-xsm font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
          <option selected class="selected">Order By P1</option>
          <option>i1</option>
          <option>i2</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <form class="mr-2">
        <select class="form-control font-size-xsm font-weight-normal text-gray" id="">
          <option selected class="selected">Order By P2</option>
          <option>i1</option>
          <option>i2</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the padding setting on `form_select` because there's too much padding and it's covering up the text. I also changed the width to `width:150px;` when you use percent width

> When using percentage (%) for width, authors must be aware that the
>   percentage is based on the element's parent, or in other words, the
>   width of the containing block. If your parent is set at 480px - as
>   demonstrated by our demo - then the percentage is based on that value.
>   So in our case 50% of 480px leaves us with 240px as a computed pixel
>   value.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/

```
.form_select{    
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  /*padding: 0.5rem 1rem;*/
  padding:0;

  background-size: .9rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 1rem) center;
  background-color: $white;
  background-image: url(img/png.svg);

  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;

  border: 1px solid red;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px  solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;

  transition: all .2s ease;

  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/gLgv8n3q/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but like that the select is not responsive. For example, with the resize the selects maintain the 150px and so in small devices like 568px and even 768px there is a lot of white space at the right of the layout because the selects are not adapting to the resize. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: True, but you can just change the width in the media query, or do you not want to do that?